# What does this bash script command mean (sed - e)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm totally new to bash scripting but i want to solve this problem..
the command is:

```
    objfil=`echo ${srcfil} | sed -e "s,c$,o,"`
```

the idea about the bash script program is to check for the source files, and check if there is an adjacent object file in the OBJ directory, if so, the rest of the program runs smoothly, if not, the iteration terminates and skips the current source file, and moves on to the next one.. it works with .c files but not on the headers, since the object filenames depend on .c files.. i want to write this command so it checks the object files not just the .c but the .h files too.. but without skipping them. i know i have to do something else too, but i need to understand what this line of command does exactly to move on. Thanks. (Sorry for my english)

UPDATE:

```
    if test -r ${curOBJdir}/${objfil}
    then
        cp -v ${srcfil} ./SAVEDSRC/${srcfil}

        fdone="NO"
        linenums=ALL
    else
        fdone="YES"
        err="${curOBJdir}/${objfil} is missing - ${srcfil} skipped)"
        echo ${err}
        echo ${err} >>${log}
    fi

    while test ${fdone} == "NO"
    do 
    #rest of code ...
```

here is the rest of the program.. i tried to comment out the "test" part to ignore the comparison just because i only want my script to work on .h files, but without checking the e.g abc.h files has an abc.o file.. (the object file generation is needed because the end of the script there's a comparison between the hexdump of the original and modified object files). The whole script is for changing the basic types with typedefs like int to sint32_t for example.

Comment: [sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)...

Comment: It is equivalent to `objfil=\`echo ${srcfil} | sed -e "s/c$/o/"\``. It replaces a `c` at the end of a line by a `o`.

Comment: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sed+-e+%22s%2Cc%24%2Co%2C%22

Comment: You need to post the rest of your script. Also, "man sed" at your command line will provide valuable information.

Comment: By the way, nominaly, `.h` files should not generate `.o` files. They should just be included in `.c` files.

Comment: @CDahn I posted the rest of the code. I've read the manual, and I'm quite over it but in this case, for me it's a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

This concrete command will substitute all c's right before line-end to o:

```
srcfill=abcd.c
objfil=`echo ${srcfil} | sed -e "s,c$,o,"`
echo $objfil
```

Output:

```
abcd.o
```

P.S. It uses a different match/replace separator: default is `/` but it uses `,`.